# What could 轰 be a contraction of to mean "what"?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

轰 can be found in some dialects, often with a 个 found on the end, to mean *what*.

This is most definitely a contraction. (Similar dialects also feature a contraction of 哪 and 样 as 孃 niang, also meaning *what*.)

What could 轰 be a contraction of?

My best guess at the moment is that it is a contraction of something like 何 + 用, but that's a stab in the dark at best.

---

To answer @dan's questions in the comments:

> What dialects use it?

I believe it is, perhaps too specifically, part of 仁富小片.

> Do you have a specific example?

[newssc [dot] org](http://scnews.newssc.org/system/20140317/000178520.html)

> “我跟你们说嘛，轰个叫做乡愁……”

Comment: haven't heard it before. what dialects use it? Do you have a specific example?

Comment: @dan I edited my post with answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Not only in Sichuan. Some Anhui dialects use it too. Probably contracted from 何麽. 哪麽 contracted to be LANG in Chongqing.